# Re-setting the whole state in setState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have a component with a state containing an `endDate` and a `startDate` (and possibly other things, like an array of data to display).
When the date range is changed (using a datepicker), I simply wrote:

```
onDateChangedHandler = (startDate, endDate) => {
  this.setState({ startDate, endDate });
}
```

Later on, another (more experienced) developer submitted a pull request, that amongst other things, changed this code to:

```
onDateChangedHandler = (startDate, endDate) => {
  const state = Object.assign({ ...this.state, startDate, endDate });
  this.setState({ ...state });
}
```

I asked him for feedback but couldn't get any answers. There are multiple things that I don't understand here:

**Isn't Object.assign without a second argument pointless?**
From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), `Object.assign(target, ...sources)` return the target with sources merged into it. So if no source it passed, it just returns `target` making the statement useless.

**Why re-spread the `state` variable when passing it to setState()?**
It should already be a copy.

But my main question is:
**Is there any benefit in re-passing the entire state to setState instead of only the modified keys?**
And are there any additional risks associated to `setState()` being asynchronous when doing that?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes; that code is wrong on all three counts.

Comment: Ori Drori answered well, but just adding another yes, that you're code is better and his is all wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is better, and you're right on every point:

1. In the line `Object.assign({ ...this.state, startDate, endDate })`, the assign just returns the object created by the spread. This `{ ...this.state, startDate, endDate }` should have been enough.
2. Correct. You don't need to clone it a second time.
3. It might cause a problem because [`setState()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) is async, and the current `this.state` might be outdated. If you need to use the current state in `setState()` use an updater function. For example: `setState((prevState) => ({ counter: prevState.counter + 1, startDate, endDate })`. However, since you don't need to include the prev state when updating the state, you can skip it in this case.

Comment: Thank you all very much for your anwers!